# How do i enter a number into a textbox and get that number back in a list for c#

Tags: c#, list, user-interface, graph

I have made a User interface using visual studio with text boxs. I want to enter a number into a text box and also add values to these elements with another text box I am using c# and visual studio.

For example if I enter 6 into the text box i want the output to be:

> A =
>   B =
>   C =
>   D =
>   E =
>   r =
>   Creating 6 elements.

After this I want to give each element values based on user input from another text box
For example:

> A =(1,3)
>   B =(2,5,6)
>   C =(4,7)
>   r  =(4,6), (5,7), (3,2)  (This a binary relation)
>   How would i go about this?

After I have created this list of elements with their values I wish to graphically represent the elements using a directed graph
For Example:

> ```
>  **A**          **B**          **C**
>  1   3-------->2  5  6<--------4   7<-
>                    |__________________|
> ```

Comment: Do you know how to create a text box using the constructor in C#, assign it's value, and add it to the page?  Basic tutorials might help you more than a SO question.

Comment: Other than this sounding like a homework assignment, I honestly have no clue as to what you actually want. Maybe I'm just dumb (highly possible)

Comment: @Gabe no no you are not dumb my question is most probably dumb

Comment: @Seano666 i have created the text box on visual studio buy dragging it onto the form. I want to then enter the value into the text box and them show up on a label. I want to then assign these elements values